# Limitar acesso WebServices para dois dominios

Tags: web-service, iis

Como faço para limitar acesso a um Web Service para apenas dois domínios?

Gostaria que apenas o domínio: `http://"ServidoX".ipesp.gov"` e o `http://"ServidoY".ipesp.gov"` possa consumir este serviço.

Já tentei modificar no Web.Config usando a Tag :

```
add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://"XXXXX".ipesp.gov,   http://"YYYY.ipesp.gov"
```

Atualmente o arquivo Web.Config está configurada desse jeito :

```
add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"
```

Também tentei restringir o acesso a aplicação no Servidor IIS , mas não adiantou. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Dê um ping (ping servidorx.ipesp.gov) para esses endereços e configure o ip restriction do IIS para permitir acesso apenas desses ips. Caso os servidores não aceitem ping procure saber qual o número ip deles.

Para configurar o IIS veja em http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889.aspx